# Is it possible to disable the deathcam?

Tags: team-fortress-2

> The Deathcam, also known as the Freeze Cam, is a gameplay feature that
> activates upon death. When you are killed, the camera zooms in on your
> killer (in the case of assists, the one that dealt the fatal blow;...
> <sub>[Deathcam](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Deathcam) - Official TF2 Wiki</sub>

I'm aware that disabling the Deathcam will put me at a disadvantage, as I won't be shown the location of my killer, but I would personally rather play without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to disable the Deathcam in TF2 per-player.

Maybe it used to be, since there's a lot of mention of a console command called `cl_disablefreezecam 1` across the internet, but there's about an equal amount of people saying it doesn't work.

There is a very good reason you can't disable it, of course: it would mean players couldn't get Freeze Cam based achievements against you.

Comment: Technically the achievements could still be unlocked when a player has freeze cam is disabled, but this is still a great point.